# SyntaxError in Django Zinnia Blog Templates

Tags: python, django, zinnia

I'm running Django 1.5.2 and installed Zinnia Blog but I'm getting a Syntax error in some of the templates. An example is in skeleton.html on this line:

```
<link rel="index" href="{% url 'zinnia_entry_archive_index' %}" />
```

The 'zinnia_entry_archive_index' part is highlighted specifically. If I remove the line, I just get the same syntax error somewhere else, which leads me to think that it's not something specifically in this line but maybe something to do with the use of the "url" part.

Do I need to have something installed to use it? Or is there something else I'm missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I thought, the error had absolutely nothing to do with Zinnia. It was a syntax error being exposed in my own code in a completely random place. I was using an exception without a try in there. Rookie error:

```
except User.DoesNotExist:
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Lesson learnt: Don't rely on the Django errors in the browser. If they're confusing, check the actual apache error logs! Because no doubt you'll see something like this:

```
File "../project/users/api/views.py", line 76
    except User.DoesNotExist:
         ^
```

It's working now at least!

Answer (score 0):

You have no "+" between the variable URL and the string 'zinnia...'

To add (concatenate) two string you need to put a plus operator between them, that seems like it would be a problem.

Comment: 'url' is used for template tags (see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-url)). It looks like it's using the correct syntax to me, can't figure it out.

Comment: -1 url isn't a string variable it's a built-in Django template tag --> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url

Comment: Oh cool, I freely admit to not being a Python or Django guy, just saw this shared on my fb feed and thought I might chime in. What's the complete error?

Comment: All good! Appreciate it nonetheless. The full error is:
SyntaxError at /blog/ invalid syntax (views.py, line 76) but it highlights {% url 'zinnia_entry_archive_index' %} as the error in skeleton.html. Problem is, there is no views.py for Zinnia. So no idea where it's really referring to.

Comment: Hmm, not particularly illuminating, though I did find this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16433035/django-url-noreversematch-works-in-3rd-party-app-but-not-my-project

Comment: Figured it out, see my answer above. Thanks for your help. :)